# How to sum and multiply specific values by a number in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing list of actions performed by persons.

After

```
SELECT COUNT(NICK) AS TOTAL, NICK, ACTION FROM ACTIONS2  GROUP BY ACTION,NICK ORDER BY NICK ASC, TOTAL DESC
```

it looks like this:

```
total   nick    action
13      0xlne   destroyed
5       0xlne   captured
5       0xlne   deployed
1       13key   destroyed
2       74pawel deployed
1       74pawel destroyed
1       74pawel captured
```

Now, I would like to multiply action destroy x75,capture x500, deploy x125 and so on, so first row should look: (13*75+5*500+5*125=4100)

```
total   nick
4100    0xlne
75      13key
```

and so on. Is there a way to correlate this few types of actions with values without creating new table, and joining them before multiply and sum?

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of using CASE/WHEN

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN action='destroyed' THEN total*75 WHEN action='captured'   THEN total*500 ELSE total*125 END), nick 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(NICK) AS TOTAL, NICK, ACTION FROM ACTIONS2  GROUP BY ACTION,NICK ORDER BY NICK ASC, TOTAL DESC) AS nicks 
GROUP by nick;
```

As a footnote: generally upper case is used for SQL reserved words and lower case for column/table names.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I tried to upvote, however I have less than 15 reputation yet. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation and sum the weighted values:

```
SELECT NICK, COUNT(*) AS totalAction
    COALESCE(SUM(ACTION='destroyed'),0)*75 +
    COALESCE(SUM(ACTION='capture'),0)*500 +
    COALESCE(SUM(ACTION='deploy'),0)*125
    as totalPoints
FROM ACTIONS2  
GROUP BY NICK 
ORDER BY NICK ASC, totalAction DESC
```

The expression

```
COALESCE(SUM(ACTION='destroyed'),0)*75
```

can aslo be written as

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN ACTION='destroyed' THEN 1 END)*75
```

Or

```
COUNT(ACTION='destroyed' OR NULL)*75
```

Or many other ways.

A little bit different approach:

```
SELECT NICK, COUNT(*) AS totalAction,
    SUM(
        CASE ACTION
            WHEN 'destroyed' THEN 75
            WHEN 'capture'   THEN 500
            WHEN 'deploy'    THEN 125
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) as totalPoints
FROM ACTIONS2  
GROUP BY NICK 
ORDER BY NICK ASC, totalAction DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, but didnt know this particular keyword